# How to create phar files on Mac?

Tags: php, bash, macos, macos-mojave, phar

I would like to pack my folder -

`phar pack -f result.phar /Users/me/FolderToPack/`

But OSX returns the following error - `Creating phar files is disabled by ini setting 'phar.readonly'.`

I tried to change `phar.readonly` value with

`php -r "ini_set('phar.readonly',0);print(ini_get('phar.readonly'));"`

But it doesn't work (the `phar.readonly` value remains equal to `1`). The PHP doc says that change of this value is not allowed in `ini` file.

What else could I do to create `phar` files on Mac (without installing additional libs/programs)?

Comment: `The PHP doc says that change of this value is not allowed in ini file`....no, that's not what it says - read it again: https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.configuration.php#ini.phar.readonly . If the value could not be changed, it wouldn't be there as an option to begin with!! The documentation says it's a bad idea to change it in a live server, for security reasons, which makes sense. But presumably, you are doing this on your own machine for development work?

Comment: It also says: _"is setting can only be unset in php.ini due to security reasons. If phar.readonly is disabled in php.ini, the user may enable phar.readonly in a script or disable it later. If phar.readonly is enabled in php.ini, a script may harmlessly "re-enable" the INI variable, but may not disable it."_ which I would expect is why your `ini_set` command didn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On macOS, creating Phar files might be disabled due to security considerations. Changing the phar.readonly value using ini_set will not work because it's a PHP_INI_SYSTEM type configuration, meaning it can only be set in the php.ini file or using other configuration methods like .htaccess (if you're using PHP as an Apache module).

Since you mentioned you don't want to install additional libraries or programs, there is still a way to create Phar files without modifying system-wide settings or installing anything extra. You can use the -d option when running the php command to override the phar.readonly setting temporarily. Here's how you can do it:

```
php -d phar.readonly=0 /path/to/phar pack -f result.phar /Users/me/FolderToPack/
```